# Разумно ли делать дубликаты библиотечных методов для того, чтобы избавиться от обработки исключений?

Tags: исключения, orm, java, jdbc

Здравствуйте.
Занимаюсь в данный момент разработкой объектно-реляционного слоя в своём приложении.
Язык программирования Java.
Суть такова: имеется класс-обёртка, в котором имеется объект Statement и объект ResultSet.
В языке Java одному Statement'у должен соответствовать один ResultSet, поэтому мой класс служит некой единицей для подключения к БД (объект static Connection там имеется), формирования запросов и работы с получившимся результирующим набором.
Данный класс у меня используется в базовом классе всех сущностных классов (один сущ. класс соответствует одной таблице в БД).
Мне бы хотелось, чтобы в базовом классе для сущностных код был максимально короток и изящен: без обработок исключений.
Для того, чтобы это было так, я написал кучу кода: в классе-обёртке (о котором говорил в начале) я продублировал методы для работы с ResultSet следующим образом:

```
public void first() {
    try {
        результат.first();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void updateString(String columnLabel, String x) {
    try {
        результат.updateString(columnLabel, x);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public String getString(int columnIndex) {
    String s = null;
    try {
        s = результат.getString(columnIndex);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return s;
}
```

"результат" - это имя объектной переменной ResultSet внутри класса. Она у меня скрытая.

Вопрос: насколько это правильно? Нормальные программисты вообще так делают или мне сдедует это удалить, а "результат" сделать public?

Comment: @Лемур, нормальные программисты  по крайней мере код возврата (а можно и результат исключения) каким-то образом в подобных случая возвращают.


Как у Вас вызывающий updateString метод поймет, что все ОК?

Comment: http://ormlite.com/ Это на всякий случай вдруг понадобится.

Answer (score 2):

Как говорится, а х... его знает, товарищ майор....
Я знавал людей, которые вообще не делают обработки исключений. Типа а нафига? Ну подумаешь упадет :) И эти люди (они правда не на жабе и не под мобильные платформы пишут), как-то живут и как-то распространяют свои поделки...
И я пытался их переубедить, что критические ситуации в проге надо обрабатывать. Раз несколько пытался. Бесполезно было. До тех пор пока не прилелето им критических люлей от одного сурового заказчика, которому надоело постоянно поднимать приложения ручками.
Вообще, исключения обрабатывать надо. А где и как - это вам вряд ли кто скажет точно, у всех свои мнения будут. 
Один бывший коллега делал один глобальный обработчик исключений на всё приложение (это опять же не на жабе), и потом подпихивал его взамем штатного и в нем чего-то там пытался обрабатывать :). Ну тоже как-то работало. Правда конечно падало, но на экран выдавались сообщения, что не просто так упало, а в стеке чойта не того или регистры попутались :):)

Главное, ну лично на мой взгляд, конечно, чтобы приложение корректно работало, и чтобы критические ситуации разрешались с меньшими потерями для пользователя. 
Иной раз, приходится тыкать обработку исключений везде и всюду, да ещё и с выводом кучи отладки в файл (с опциональным включением/выключением самого вывода и настройкой уровней вывода отладки - от минимальной до максимальной, т.е. чуть ли вообще не всё подряд писать, что в приложении делается, а не только об исключениях), если прога уходит куда-
нибудь далеко и пешком не пойдёшь, а на самолетах нынче дорого :). Так в случае проблем, хотя бы по этому файлику можно бывает разобраться дистанционно...
А в общем лирика это всё. Тут вам решать, как и что делать, ибо прога ваша и вам за нее отвечать :)

Comment: Ну, глобальный обработчик — это, конечно, удобно, но что делать, если одни и те же исключения могут выпадать на разных уровнях?

Я обычно просто делаю прослойку для обработки исключений, где реализую методы bool action(args) навроде этого:

    public bool initInput()
        {
        if (this.in != null)
            return true;
        
        try
            {
            this.in = new DataInputStream(this.socket.getInputStream());
            }
        catch (IOException e)
            {
            return false;
            }
        
        return true;
        }

Comment: @Bars у меня кровь из глаз пошла, вы когда-нибудь читали про то как надо форматировать свой код?

Comment: формат как формат. просто на жабе один формат на С другой. кто как привык. я тоже жабий формат пока плохо перевариваю. путаюсь в фигурных скобках. поскоку оч давно программирую на С, С++, С# и как-то к иному структурированию привык :) дело вкуса :):):) и к конкретике вопроса отношения не имеет :) желающий да прочтет и такой код :)

Comment: @Demon051 даже в С,С++ и С# фигурные скобки не сдвигают относительно того элемента, к которому они относятся.

Comment: э... это кто как и где привык. зависит от места работы как бы... как в коллективе люди привыкли, так и делают...
я не одно место работы сменил, с разными правилами сталкивался. :)

Comment: Ну, я если честно, *именно такое* вижу впервые.

Comment: @Demon051 есть общепринятые правила, и если в какой-то команде этому не следуют, то это не значит что это правильно. Как минимум можно в команде поднять вопрос о том, чтобы следовать правилам. И правила не от балды выработаны, они повышают читабельность кода и унифицируют его, чтобы не надо было переучиваться при смене работы/команды.

Comment: @Russtam, @avp, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style#Whitesmiths_style

Такая привычка у меня выработана еще с Паскаля, когда его учили наряду с КуМиром. Ничего не могу с этим поделать. @Russtam, а ты где читал о том, как нужно форматировать свой код?

Comment: @Bars, ну значит, мне просто повезло (а *такие формы* даже в вики попали).

Пишите, конечно, как Вам удобно (но не удивляйтесь, если Ваш код люди будут просто игнорировать).

Comment: @Bars было у Оракла на сайте, сейчас 404 выдает. Но можно посмотреть тут http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javaguide.html
+ современные IDE (Eclipse, Netbeans, IDEA) 80% работы за вас сделают.

Comment: @Russtam, вот из-за таких "мануалов" люди и пишут как получиться.

Ну какой разумный человек начнет читать (да еще и запоминать???) такой объем писанины?

По хорошему, все рекомендации по формату кодирования должны умещаться на страничке (с примерами на 3-х) и сводиться к:

 "вот это местный босс считает красиво".

Comment: Не вижу смысла далее продолжать спор о том, что кому удобно. Я, кстати, даже тут уже поднимал вопрос об этом.

Если будут игнорировать мой код — значит у самих все хорошо и мой код просто не нужен. Когда мне что-то нужно, я приспосабливаюсь к тому что мне дают.

> Ну, я если честно, именно такое вижу впервые.

@avp, врете. http://hashcode.ru/questions/204550/